# Installing TensorFlow on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 3B, meed 64 bit OS. Anyone get 64 bit OS yet?

Tags: python, pi-3b+

I am following the instruction from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/install/install_linux).
My installed python version is 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux

```
(tensorflow) pi@The32GB:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The error message is

```
tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

The problem is my Stretch still 32 bit OS.

There is Xubuntu 18.04 LTS (the default edition, 64-bit) at https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/xubuntu

Is there anyone already success installing Tensorflow using Xubuntu 64 bit OS on Raspbi 3B?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got 64bit Devuan on the 3B.

Comment: I think would like to try Xubuntu 18.04 64 bit OS on Raspi 3B. Because many instruction based on Strecth (ubuntu family).

Have you try install tensorflow on Devuan yet?

Comment: No, sorry, not such a Gogole fan.

Comment: I am trying gentoo 64 bit os from https://github.com/sakaki-/gentoo-on-rpi3-64bit

Comment: I hope you are very patient.